# Gentle introduction to quasi-geodesics

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

Compared to the concept of [geodesics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) the concept of **quasi-geodesics** seems to be substantially harder to grasp and digest. I was given a promising hint to the concept of quasi-geodesics [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/291013/1792) but the usual references didn't reveal something like an "easy access" to the concept:

- [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=quasi-geodesics) [the very first hit pointing to a paper of G. Perelman]
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#Q)
- [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Quasi-geodesic_line)

So I am still looking for something like a "gentle introduction to quasi-geodesics".

Comment: The Wikipedia and EoM articles to which you linked discuss two unrelated concepts that go by the same name "quasi-geodesic". One, defined in Wikipedia, is useful in negatively curved (hyperbolic) spaces. The other, described in EoM, is mostly used in positively curved (Alexandrov) spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is rather self-serving, but I do discuss quasigeodesics in my book with Erik Demaine, *[Geometric Folding Algorithms: Linkages, Origami, Polyhedra](http://www.gfalop.org)*, pp.372-380.  I spent some time absorbing the Russian geometry literature before writing that section.  Some of the same material is revisited in a more elementary presentation in my book with Satyan Devadoss, *[Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/DCG/)*, pp.200-205:

[image: Figure 6.35]

I would be interested myself if there is a more "gentle introduction."  I don't think so.  And at least the way I have presented it in these books, it is, I think, rather easy to understand.

Comment: :Thank you very much! I'll try to get your book.

Answer (score 0):

I read from Vandereycken's PhD thesis (http://web.math.princeton.edu/~bartv) that quasi-geodesics are first order approximations, also called retractions (used in optimization).  It is a cheap approximation to a geodesic.